# (Plugin) Icon needed beside the post title

Tags: plugins

I need a plugin to do some posting like this. The icon "Hot!" will appear in front of the post title. Please suggest me any plugin for this. [image]

Comment: you can use it easily by custom coding  there  are many plugin but not the  one which will fully satisfy your need  so go for custom coding and you can make it easily

Comment: I dont prefer custom coding. Is there any ready plugin?

Comment: seeking Plugin recommendation is an off-topic here.

Comment: Oh really? Where should i seek then? Please Recommend

Comment: try to use this one if it help you  http://wordpress.org/plugins/title-icons/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily by using the filter the_title. Below is the custom code which you can use in your theme's functions.php file.

```
function new_title( $title ) {
    $new_title = 'nic ' . $title;
    return $new_title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'new_title' );
```

The above will add "**nic**" prior to post title.

Similarly you can use the icon image in place of the text 'nic' and style accordingly to achieve what you are looking for.

Hope it helps!
Thanks

Comment: Hi Murati it does help! However i want to put it only on popular post. How can i do it?

Comment: Hi Nic, what is "popular" here!!! categories or custom posts?